# MaxListenersExceededWarning: Possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. With NEXTJS

Tags: next.js, stripe-payments, webhooks

error:

MaxListenersExceededWarning: Possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 server@pages@/api/stripe/webhook listeners added to [EventEmitter]. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit

When happend?
This error only happens when the stripe webhook is called

Note: I have one application in nodejs with the same code but using express and this doesnt happen

---

How Stripe CLI Webhook look like :
[image]

and must be like this!
[image]

NextJS Console with error
[image]

code:

```
import { Readable } from "node:stream";
import { NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse } from "next";
import Stripe from "stripe";
import { stripeRelevantEvents } from "@/lib/stripe/event";
import { getPlanFromPriceId } from "@/lib/stripe/plans";
import { stripe } from "@/lib/stripe";
import prisma from "@/lib/prisma";
import { env_server } from "@/env/server.mjs";
// EXPORT config to tell Next.js NOT to parse the body
export const config = {
  api: {
    bodyParser: false,
  },
};

async function buffer(readable: Readable) {
  const chunks: Buffer[] = [];
  for await (const chunk of readable) {
    chunks.push(typeof chunk === "string" ? Buffer.from(chunk) : chunk);
  }
  return Buffer.concat(chunks);
}


export default async function webhookHandler( req: NextApiRequest,  res: NextApiResponse ){

  // POST /api/stripe/webhook – listen to Stripe webhooks
  if(req.method === "POST"){

      const rawBody = await buffer(req);
      const signature = req.headers['stripe-signature'];
      const webhookSecret = env_server.STRIPE_WEBHOOK_SECRET;
      let event: Stripe.Event;
    
      //Verify stripe
      if (!signature || !webhookSecret) {
        console.log("Webhook error: Missing Stripe-Signature or Stripe-Secret-Webhook.");
        return res.status(400).send("Webhook error: Missing Stripe-Signature or Stripe-Secret-Webhook.");
      } 
    
      try {
        event = stripe.webhooks.constructEvent( rawBody, signature, webhookSecret );
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(`⚠️ Webhook signature verification failed ${error}`);
        return res.status(400).send("Webhook error: Webhook signature verification failed.");
      }

      if (!stripeRelevantEvents.has(event.type)) {
        console.log(`‍♀️ Unhandled event type: ${event.type}`);
        return res.status(400).send(`‍♀️ Unhandled event type: ${event.type}`);
      }

      console.log(`Event type: ${event.type}`)
        
      try {
        //CHECKOUT SESSION
        if (event.type === "checkout.session.completed") {
          const checkoutSession = event.data.object as Stripe.Checkout.Session;
          if ( !checkoutSession.client_reference_id  || !checkoutSession.customer ) {
            console.log("Missing items in stripe webhook callback");
            return res.status(400).send("Missing items in stripe webhook callback");
          }
            const userId =  checkoutSession.client_reference_id;
            const stripeId = checkoutSession.customer.toString();

            await prisma.subscription.update({
              where: {
                userId
              },
              data: {
                stripeId
              },
            });
            return res.status(200).json({ received: true });
        };
      
        if(event.type === "customer.subscription.updated"){

          const subscriptionUpdate = event.data.object as Stripe.Subscription;
          const priceId = subscriptionUpdate.items.data[0].price.id;
          const stripeId = subscriptionUpdate.customer.toString();
          const plan = getPlanFromPriceId(priceId);
        
          await prisma.subscription.updateMany({
            where:{
              stripeId
            },
            data:{
              plan: plan.key,
              //Period
              stripeSubscriptionId: subscriptionUpdate.id,
              currentPeriodStart:subscriptionUpdate.current_period_start,
              currentPeriodEnd:subscriptionUpdate.current_period_end,
              cancelAtPeriodEnd:subscriptionUpdate.cancel_at_period_end,
            }
          });
          return res.status(200).json({ received: true });
        }
      
        if(event.type === "customer.subscription.deleted"){
          const subscriptionDeleted = event.data.object as Stripe.Subscription;
          const stripeId = subscriptionDeleted.customer.toString();
          await prisma.subscription.updateMany({
            where:{
              stripeId
            },
            data:{
              plan: "free",
              //Period
              currentPeriodStart:null,
              currentPeriodEnd:null,
              cancelAtPeriodEnd:null,
            }
          });
          return res.status(200).json({ received: true });
        }
      
      } catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
        return res.status(400).send("Webhook error: Webhook handler failed. View Logs.");
      }

    return res.status(200).json({ received: true });

  } else {
    res.setHeader("Allow", ["POST"]);
    return res.status(405).send(`Method ${req.method} Not Allowed`);
  }
}
```

Notes:

- I'm use pages api
- When the error happens my database is not updated :C
- I use prisma like ORM

Subscription Model

```
model Subscription {
  id                 String @id @default(auto()) @map("_id") @db.ObjectId
  userId             String @unique @db.ObjectId
  plan               PlanKey @default(free)   //free plan by default

  //Stripe Id's
  stripeId             String?   //Stripe customer id
  stripeSubscriptionId String?  

  //current period
  currentPeriodStart Float?
  currentPeriodEnd   Float?

  //cancel
  cancelAtPeriodEnd  Boolean?

  createdAt          DateTime        @default(now())
  updatedAt          DateTime        @updatedAt

  //tables
  user User @relation(fields: [userId], references: [id], onDelete: Cascade)
}
```

Resolve the MaxListenersExceededWarning when use stripe webhook with NextJs

Comment: If you remove any Prisma-specific code and handle many events, do you still hit the error?

I suspect this has something to do with Prisma connections/disconnections and your code likely hitting some connection maximum.

Comment: I remove all the prisma code and the problem persist :C

Comment: @JEANPABLOCALDERONRAMIREZ did you ever figure out what this is? I get this warning in dev mode when revalidating many paths.